# Ambari Custom Hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigdata

I've downloaded and builded some BigData services (Hadoop, Hive, Spark,...) and I want to deploy it using Ambari.
Ambari has set some versions (HDP Stacks) and I would like to configure it with my own compiled binaries.

Is there someone who could help me with this task? Some kind of guide or tutorial about it?

Really Thanked,
Sartions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDP is a stack definition for Ambari, what you're asking for is a custom stack definition. You can define your own stack by following the outline provided by Ambari on its wiki: [How-To Define Stacks and Services](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/How-To+Define+Stacks+and+Services).